# Is the following text grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, idioms

Would you be so kind as to help me correct this text? I am currently trying to incorporate more 成语 and more complex vocabulary in my writing.

--

首先，你必须试探你的对手，因为他的话靠不住。不要让他的想法弄垮得稀巴烂你的思想。其次，你应该每天选择自己的战斗。如果你有对交战的渴望，请不要冲动地行动，由于交战的成本比仔谨慎的成本高得多。不仅观察别人，还要记得他们的想法。因此，首先了解你自己的难事，然后理解别人的努力。结果，你变得更加熟练，因此将来你超越自己。尽管看起来有些事情超出了你的能力，但别放心，你不是辅助角色，也不是其他人的替罪羊。只要你相信自己，你就可能成功了。最后，其他人可能会欺负你，但尝试忽略他们并你注意你的目标。你可能做不可思议的事情！

Comment: It is not a good sign that I have to guess what you tried to say. To write a coherent paragraph,  knowing how to write correctly structured sentences is not enough, you have to learn how to connect them in a coherent way

Comment: What do you mean “别靠他"?this is a mistake here , not only grammar mistake .

Comment: You should not remove your question because others might be helped by reading it. This is the reason why stack exchange exists.

Comment: What the OP wanted was for contributors to correct, improve his grammar ONLY, and not comment on, or worse criticize the substance of the contents of the piece, which, understandably, the OP must have been proud of because the piece is actually a tour-de-force of the OP's inner most thoughts on how he sees and should conduct himself in various situations of conflict, real or imagined. (I assume OP is a male judging from the contents?)

Comment: Questions are kept around to be useful for future readers.  If you're finding the answers useful, please upvote, and consider "accepting" an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation

- <s>删掉的内容</s>
- **增加的内容**
- (注释)

首先，你必须 <s>试探</s>**观察** 你的对手，因为他的话 <s>靠不住</s>**不可信**。不要让他的想法弄垮 <s>得稀巴烂</s> 你的思想。其次，你应该每天选择自己的战斗 (not sure what you want to say here)。如果你有对交战的渴望，请不要冲动地行动，<s>由于</s>**因为** 交战的成本比仔谨慎 **思考** 的成本高得多。不仅 **要** 观察别人，还要记得他们的想法。因此，首先了解你自己的 <s>难事</s>**难处** ，然后理解别人的努力。<s>结果，</s>**最终** 你 **会** 变得更加 <s>熟练</s>**成熟**，<s>因此</s>**并且**(因此 and 结果/最终 are duplicated) 将来你**会**超越自己。尽管看起来有些事情超出了你的能力，但别 <s>放心</s>**担心**(I don't known what you want to say here, but it should not be 别放心)，你不是辅助角色，也不是其他人的替罪羊。只要你相信自己，你就可能成功 <s>了</s>。最后，其他人可能会欺负你，但 **请** 尝试忽略他们 **，** 并 <s>你</s> <s>注意</s>**专注于** 你 **自己** 的目标。你可能做 **到** 不可思议的事情！

Note: I still don't get what you want to say. When I made the corrections, I treated each sentence as a standalone sentence.

Comment: 你应该选择自己的战斗 = choose your fight = choose what to fight for

Comment: "Choose your fight" is  more like "选择自己的戰場"  You have to pick the fight that is just and that you can win

Answer (score 0):

要是你对交战的渴望，就别冲动的行动。
This is wrong too .you should say ,
要是你有对交战的渴望，就别冲动地行动。